# Bootstrapping mean and lower and upper bound

Tags: r, stata

let's say, I have two variable x and y:

```
X   Y
1   2
3   9
7   16
10  17
14  23
```

In this case I want to resample y 250 times using bootstrapping with replacement. Which would look something like this:

```
X    Y    y1   y2  z_y z_y1 z_y2  mean_z lower_bound  upper_bound 
1    2    2    9    .    .    .    .        .              . 
3    9    16   23
7   16    16   17
10  17    23   2
14  23    9    16
```

I want to generate z score for y, y1 and y2 wrt to each values of x. Then I want to calculate mean value for z for given x. and also want to compute lower and upper bound of confidence interval for each mean z score wrt x.

How can I do this in stata or R.

Comment: I don't understand the point of this, why are you doing this? What is your goal?

Comment: This [tutorial](https://www.stata.com/features/overview/bootstrap-sampling-and-estimation/) should help you to do bootstrapping in Stata. You can probably copy the first example and replace `bootstrap r(p50)` by `bootstrap r(mean)`.

Comment: @user2974951 I want to do the following:
"We construct 95% confidence bands using the bootstrap, with 250 replications. In each replication, and independently for rural and urban areas, we first resample clusters separately from each NFHS round. We then reestimate all the difference-in-differences at each replication and calculate the value of the lower and upper bands for each point on a grid as the 2.5 and 97.5 percentiles from the bootstrap distribution."

which has been done in the following paper: https://are.berkeley.edu/~aprajit/mahajan_tarozzi_06_childhealth.pdf (page 459).

Comment: @Maultasche this I tried earlier but it did  not give me what I want.

Comment: Where does the 250 replications fit in your dataframe? Are you imagining 250 columns, or 250 rows?

Comment: @C.Murtaugh I am trying to think what they are doing. I still do not really know what they mean by the above statement. It would be great if you could help in understand what they have essentially did.
However I feel they are just resampling the data, then calculating the z score, followed by calculation of cdfs and its difference. But I really don't understand fully.

Comment: You can calculate the z-scores before resampling, as they do not change, as the mean and s.d. in the normalization process are are given (healthy child). You need to resample the z-scores, here you can search for **panel bootstrap**, **cluster bootstrap** or **block bootstrap** and look for a function that just samples with replacement. I guess then you need to calculate some quantiles based on the sampled values and then calculate the diff-in-diff values. Without knowing how the data looks like, it is hard to give a solution to the question.